# Screen-saver settings WMIC command fails in Server 2016

Tags: batch-file, wmic, windows-server-2016, windows-screensaver

I have this script which outputs the screen-saver settings to a file.

```
wmic desktop get ScreenSaverActive,ScreenSaverSecure,ScreenSaverTimeout > d:\output\ScreenSaver.txt
```

It's working fine in Server 2008 and Server 2012 but in Server 2016 it just fills the file with "FALSE"-es parameters.

How can I make it to work on Server 2016?

one of the outputs:

```
Name=NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
ScreenSaverActive=FALSE
ScreenSaverSecure=
ScreenSaverTimeout=
```

here is a pic:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/20kRg.jpg

Comment: If you use `WMIC /Output:"D:\output\ScreenSaver.txt" Desktop Get Name,ScreenSaverActive,ScreenSaverSecure,ScreenSaverTimeout /Value`, the output file should better show you if there are blank or problem entries and which users they belong to. If you need help following that output, then [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49234425/edit) to include that output, highlighting it and clicking on the `{}` button to format it appropriately.

Comment: ok, one of my outputs was:

Name=NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
ScreenSaverActive=FALSE
ScreenSaverSecure=
ScreenSaverTimeout=

but it is not true, there is screen saver turned on in this server, and it's idle time is 15 minutes

Comment: So are you telling me that you've logged into the desktop as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` and that 'user' has a screensaver set. _It seems rather odd that were this very limited account be necessary to log into, GUI screensaver settings would be used, set or necessary._

Comment: actually it dosent matter what user is it because its the same with all users. here's my user:

Name=OFFICE\xameri
ScreenSaverActive=FALSE
ScreenSaverSecure=
ScreenSaverTimeout=

Comment: If this powershell code: `GWmi win32_desktop | FT Name,ScreenSaverActive,ScreenSaverSecure,ScreenSaverTimeout -A`, shows the same information, then I'm afraid you'll have to try to find an alternative to WMI to get your information.

Comment: i have add pic to the main post

Comment: Got the same info...i'll try to find alternatives. thanks!